# Delete facebook Image from Facebook page. PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I had a problem when I try to delete a photo uploaded by the PHP SDK, the error is: `Permissions error thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1237`

The code is:

```
$facebook->setAccessToken(USERACCESSTOKEN);
$facebook->api("/PHOTOID?access_token=PAGEACCESSTOKEN","DELETE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow deletion of photos through third party apps. Its a security restriction.

Comment: I cannot access facebook developer site from office else I would have searched the link for you. But I can assure you I have tried hard deleting contents from my app through all workarounds but It simply does not work now. They don't allow deletion of content , you can only create it :)

Comment: But i can delete post... o.O  It's a very strange thing.

Comment: Mmm, i have an idea... Can I delete albums instead?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Facebook API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) you can delete photos posted from your app

> by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to PROFILE_ID/photos with the user access token or app access_token.

Comment: Can you give me the PHP code for this? Because i don't know what is an HTTP DELETE REQUEST. Sorry.

Comment: it's the same as you did in your code ($facebook->api....), you'll just have to add "profile_id/photos" instead of "photoId" the only thing i'm not sure about is how to specify photo (if it's even possible), you should probably explore documentation a bit, see if it's mentioned anywhere.

Comment: So, like this i think..$facebook->api("/".$PAGEID."/photos?access_token=".$PAGETOKEN,"DELETE");
But in the documentation doesn't speak about PHOTOS ID, so how facebook can understand whick of my photos i want to delete? o.O

Comment: I'm afraid i can't answer that, it might be the case when all of the photos, added by your app will be deleted. Like i said, you should probably investigate that some more